# refreshing page showing 404 error using Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, server

Hi I uploaded my react app on server and make it live. It's working fine but whenever I refresh any page of application. it's returning 404 error. what should I do ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When your app load. The react-router handle Router. The Route change is handled by Router itself but on refreshing the request goes to nginx where that specific route doesn't exist.

To resolve this issue you need to load root file. try this solution.

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
sudo nano default
```

in default file update location

```
location {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there please add this in your **nginx.conf**

```
location / {
 try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

The problem is whenever you are trying to refresh the page it cannot find that  route on **nginx** hence you get **404** whereas when you are browsing the app it just works fine because those things are handled by browser itself.